# proof of existence in the recursion theorem in set theory

Tags: set-theory, recursion

consider [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem) theorem of set theory, the recursion theorem. On Wikipedia there is a proof of uniqueness but no proof of existence, I would like to see an existence proof.

Comment: Brief answer: consider the intersection of all *relations* satisfying the recurrence requirement. Show that this intersection is indeed a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show by induction that for any $n$, there is a unique function $F_n$ with domain $n+1$ that satisfies the recursion equations. The base case is $F_0 = \{(0,a)\}$ and then $F_{n+1}=F_n\cup\{(n+1,f(F_n(n))\}$ satisfies the equations provided $F_n$ does, and is unique by the same proof as the uniqueness proof on wikipedia. Then take $F=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}F_n$ and prove it has the required properties.

Comment: This sounds dangerously like defining $n\mapsto F_n$ by recursion on $n$, i.e., an application of the theorem being proved.

Comment: @AndreasBlass It sounds dangerously like that, but I don't believe it is. I edited to clarify that the function $F_n$ with those properties is unique.

Comment: The apparent danger is mainly due to the notation $F_n$, and it would disappear if you avoid that notation. For example, define "$g$ is good for $n$" to mean $g$ is a function with domain $n+1$ that satisfies the recursion equations. By induction on $n$, there is,  for each $n$, a unique function that is good for $n$. Also, any two good functions agree on the intersection of their domains. The union of all the good functions is the desired $F$. (It's "the same" as your argument, but it doesn't even look like a definition by recursion.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass ok, I can get behind that.

Comment: @AndreasBlass ,  spaceisdarkgreen where does this proof exist? maybe some some article or textbook... (it looks simple, but I just don't want to "invent the bicycle") e.g. Jech's "Set Theory" contains more advanced transfinite recursion theorem, but not this one.

Comment: (I mean Hrbacek & Jech "Introduction to Set Theory" also contains it, but I don't feel well when I read it... (compared to reading proofs from "Set Theory"))

Comment: @ged I'd expect some version of this proof to be in most set theory textbooks. Unfortunately, my textbooks are at my office and I'm at home, hiding from the coronavirus for the foreseeable future, so I can't check the books. Jech's proof of the transfinite recursion theorem should be simplifiable to give the result you want, and it might be a good exercise to carry out the simplification explicitly.

Comment: @ged not sure why you don't feel well when you read it. Enderton's set theory book has it. Many omit cause the natural numbers are a special case, but some include as a warm-up / motivation. Agree with Andreas in general.

Comment: Yeah, I feel much better now about "Introduction to Set Theory", I was wrong. (I verified these in Isabelle/ZF.)Thanks!

Comment: There is also this nice constructive proof of this in Ch. II of [Intuitionistic set theory](http://publish.uwo.ca/~jbell/INTBOOK(Repaired).pdf) by John Bell, in case anyone was wondering :).