# Characterizing infinite Dedekind-finite sets.

Tags: logic, set-theory, infinity, foundations

> Is the following true in $\text{ZF}$?

> A set $X$ is an infinite Dedekind-finite set if and only for every bijection $f: X \to X$ there exists a partition $X = C \cup Y$ with $C$ a finite set and $Y$ an infinite Dedekind-finite set such that $f(C) = C$. Moreover, the set $X$ can be completely partitioned into finite sets $C_\iota$ such that $f(C_\iota) = C_\iota$ with $\iota$ ranging over an infinite index set.

**My work**

This research endeavor came about from my work found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3753310/432081).

I couldn't find this question as a duplicate but before getting bogged down in the details I wanted to just get some quick feedback (please excuse the laziness - I am not an expert in set theory).

Comment: To avoid trivialities,  you should add that $C$ is nonempty.

Comment: Please don't modify your question after receiving an answer. It is now completely unclear what was the original question that Noah had answered.

Comment: To your question, it is fairly easy to prove that if $f\colon X\to X$ is a permutation, then the orbit of every point is either finite (i.e. cyclical) or equipotent to $\Bbb Z$. If a set is Dedekind-finite it cannot have subsets which are equipotent to $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila A succinct way of putting out the argument. For some reason when I see 'Dedekind-finite' I (still) get 'spooked-out'. But thanks to the guidance from both you and Noah (over the years!) I'm slowly coming around.

Comment: ROLLBACK COMPLETE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (mostly) true.

In one direction, given $f:X\rightarrow X$, for each $a\in X$ we can consider the orbit of $a$ under $f$, $$orb_f(a)=\{f^{z}(a): z\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$$ If $X$ is Dedekind-finite, each $orb_f(a)$ must itself be finite, and by definition we have $f(orb_f(a))=orb_f(a)$ and $X=\bigcup_{a\in X}orb_f(a)$.

In the other direction, suppose $X$ is Dedekind-infinite. WLOG let $X=\mathbb{Z}\sqcup Y$. Then consider the self-bijection $f$ which shifts $\mathbb{Z}$ via $z\mapsto 1+z$ and is the identity on $Y$. Clearly we cannot partition $X$ into finite  $f$-invariant pieces. However, at the same time we may still be forced to have some finite nonempty $f$-fixed sets: namely, if $Y$ itself is infinite but Dedekind-finite. So there is a slight subtlety there: the *strong* version of your property fully characterizes Dedekind-finiteness, but the weak version (the guaranteed existence of just one such $C$) doesn't.

Comment: Can you explain why the $orb_f(a)$ must be finite and not countable, please?

Comment: @OlivierRoche If the orbit were countably infinite then $X$ wouldn't be Dedekind-finite. (Remember, "Dedekind-finite" means "no countably infinite subset.")

Comment: That's not the definition I had in mind but you are right, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Noah's answer here is an improved presentation.

---

Title: Decomposing automorphisms of infinite Dedekind-finite sets.

> Is the following true in $\text{ZF}$?

Let $X$ be an infinite set.

Here is the decomposition statement,

Proposition 1: If the set $X$ is Dedekind-finite set then for every bijection $f: X \to X$ there exists a partition

$\tag 1 \{ orb_f(a) \mid a\in X\}$

of $X$ into blocks with a finite number of elements such that $f\bigr(orb_f(a)\bigr) = orb_f(a)$ for each block. Moreover, $f$ is a bijective mapping on any invariant (restricted) domain.

To show the 'converse', we state the following,

Proposition 2: If  $X$ is Dedekind-infinite set then there exists a bijection $f: X \to X$ and a set $N \subset X$ satisfying $f(N) \subsetneq N$.